# Groupby sum vs cumsum - returns dataframe vs series

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, cumsum

I noticed that when we `groupby` a `dataframe` & `sum` it we get a full `dataframe` in return:

```
dict1 = {'A': {0: 'A0', 1: 'A0', 2: 'A0', 3: 'A0', 4: 'A1', 5: 'A1', 6: 'A1', 7: 'A1', 8: 'A1', 9: 'A1'}, 'B': {0: 'B0', 1: 'B1', 2: 'B2', 3: 'B3', 4: 'B4', 5: 'B5', 6: 'B6', 7: 'B7', 8: 'B8', 9: 'B9'}, 'C': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9}, 'D': {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 13, 4: 14, 5: 15, 6: 16, 7: 17, 8: 18, 9: 19}, 'E': {0: 'E0', 1: 'E1', 2: 'E0', 3: 'E1', 4: 'E0', 5: 'E1', 6: 'E0', 7: 'E1', 8: 'E0', 9: 'E1'}}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

```
A   E 
A0  E0    22
    E1    24
A1  E0    48
    E1    51
Name: D, dtype: int64
```

But when I do a `cumsum` it returns only the resultant cumulative series.
Why do they behave differently? And how can I make `cumsum` return along with the grouped `dataframe` without assigning it back?

```
df2.groupby(['A','E'])['D'].cumsum()
```

```
0    10
1    11
2    22
3    24
4    14
5    15
6    30
7    32
8    48
9    51
Name: D, dtype: int64
```

**Edit:**
I thought it would be an easy fix and I will be able to handle the rest of it. But based on your comments so far, it takes me away from my end goal. I want to ultimately achieve sum, mean, cumsum on multiple variables in one group-by like this:

```
df2.groupby(['A','E']).agg({'D':'cumsum','C':lambda x: 4*np.sum(x)})
```

But it gives an output like this:

```
    D   C
0   10.0    NaN
1   11.0    NaN
2   22.0    NaN
3   24.0    NaN
4   14.0    NaN
5   15.0    NaN
6   30.0    NaN
7   32.0    NaN
8   48.0    NaN
9   51.0    NaN
(A0, E0)    NaN 8.0
(A0, E1)    NaN 16.0
(A1, E0)    NaN 72.0
(A1, E1)    NaN 84.0
```

So isn't there a way it can be achieved without separately handling cumsum?

Comment: It creates a new column, you  always have to assign back. You chain with `.assign` if that's what you needed -

Comment: sum is an aggregation, cumsum is a transformation. Have a look here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregation

and also at the Transformation tab on the same page

Comment: Note that .sum *also* returns a series, just with a multiindex

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to understand this based on the behavior you are already seeing in your 2 scripts. `pd.Series.cumsum()` returns another series of the same length as column `D` for each group, while your lambda function returns a single value for each group. This causes a difference in the returned indexes.

All you have to do is to use another lambda function to capture the complete cumsum operation at the level of each group. This lambda function returns a list object as an aggregation instead of a series output as a transformation.

```
t = {
    'D': lambda x: list(x.cumsum()),
    'C': lambda x: 4*np.sum(x)
    }

result = df2.groupby(['A','E']).agg(t)
result
```

```
                  D   C
A  E                   
A0 E0      [10, 22]   8
   E1      [11, 24]  16
A1 E0  [14, 30, 48]  72
   E1  [15, 32, 51]  84
```

This will return a dataframe at the level of your groups formed by A and E columns.

However, if you want the dataframe with the same indexes as the original, you can just `explode` the new column `D`

```
t = {
    'D': lambda x: list(x.cumsum()),
    'C': lambda x: 4*np.sum(x)
    }

result = df2.groupby(['A','E']).agg(t).explode('D')
result
```

```
        D   C
A  E         
A0 E0  10   8
   E0  22   8
   E1  11  16
   E1  24  16
A1 E0  14  72
   E0  30  72
   E0  48  72
   E1  15  84
   E1  32  84
   E1  51  84
```

---

**EDIT 1: Additional info based on my comments**

- Simply put, `sum` is an aggregation and returns a single value (float/int) for each group, while `cumsum` is a transformation and returns a series with the same number of rows as the input.
- `cumsum` basically transforms the given input series (rows for column D for each group) and returns another series.
- The `sum` returns series with the indexes as the first script in my answer, and the `cumsum`, returns the indexes as the second script in my answer. When Pandas tries to reconcile them, it stacks the indexes because they don't match.
- For example, for the group (A1,E0) -> `cumsum` returns a series with 3 values [14, 30, 48] while `sum` returns an aggregation of the value 72

**EDIT 2: Code with `transform` on groupby as per your comments**

If you want to avoid using lambda functions, as I understand from your comments, you can use `transform` method on a groupby object but this doesn't allow passing multiple transformations for different columns at once as a dict. So you will still have to reassign these columns.

```
grouper = df2.groupby(['A','E'])                #<- create grouper

df2['C_new'] = grouper['C'].transform('sum')    #<- use your lambda function here if you need
df2['D_new'] = grouper['D'].transform('cumsum') #<- transformation here
print(df2)
```

```
    A   B  C   D   E  C_new  D_new
0  A0  B0  0  10  E0      2     10
1  A0  B1  1  11  E1      4     11
2  A0  B2  2  12  E0      2     22
3  A0  B3  3  13  E1      4     24
4  A1  B4  4  14  E0     18     14
5  A1  B5  5  15  E1     21     15
6  A1  B6  6  16  E0     18     30
7  A1  B7  7  17  E1     21     32
8  A1  B8  8  18  E0     18     48
9  A1  B9  9  19  E1     21     51
```

Comment: I can manage it that way but I don't think lambda is causing the issue here. Actually lambda function is a compulsion for me as I want to multiply the standard function with a factor 4 (I know no other way). But if you take that out and use sum directly like this: `df2.groupby(['A','E']).agg({'D':'cumsum','C':'sum'})`, it still gives 2 different series as @Chrysophylaxs mentioned before.

Comment: Ofcourse it does, because the `sum` operation returns 1 value for each group while `cumsum` returns a series for each group. This is what I was showing you with the 2 examples.

Comment: Simply put, `sum` is an aggregation and returns a single object (float/int) for each group, while `cumsum` is a transformation and returns the same number of rows as the input. it basically transforms given input series (rows for column D for each group) and returns another series.

Comment: The `sum` returns series with the indexes as the first script in my answer, and the `cumsum` individually, returns the indexes as the second script in my answer. When pandas reconcile them, it stacks the indexes because they dont match.

Comment: For example, for the group (A1,E0) -> `cumsum` returns a series with 3 values [14, 30, 48]  while `sum` returns an aggregation of the value 72

Comment: Hope that clarifies your question. do let me know if you have any more questions. thanks!

Comment: I appreciate your response, and I understand how 2 functions are behaving. But I won't solve it that way as getting more lambda would slow it down & it's a big df. So in nutshell I understand that I have to assign `cumsum` series separately back to the original dataframe.

Comment: Correct, you can use `transform` method on `groupby` as well directly. I have added some code for your reference.

Comment: Check edit 2 in my answer